# Task bar is displayed on lock screen

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, ubuntu-dock

As illustrated [here](https://uphinhnhanh.com/images/2018/11/07/IMG_20181107_200043.jpg), my computer always displays taskbar (Ubuntu dock) after waking from sleep:

[image]

I searched online for a solution but it didn't quite help me at all. Sometimes, it'll show the message: **Your system has an internal error** or *whatever*. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Hey @pomsky, even if I restart the computer, it won't help because when I need to suspend it, and later open it up, it still has that error. Could you find some solution to help me out, please?

Comment: Try restarting GNOME shell by pressing <Alt><f2>, then typing `r` and pressing <Enter>.